# STL vector push_back() memory double free

Tags: c++, stl, vector, push-back

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

I have the a problem of the double freeing of memory in the following program.

The debugger shows that the issue is in the `push_back()` function.

**Class A:**

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int x);
        int x;
};

A::A(int x) {
    this->x = x;
}
```

**Class B:**

```
class B {
    public:
        B(int x);
        ~B();
        A* a;
};

B::B(int x) {
    this->a = new A(x);
}

B::~B() {
    delete a;
}
```

**Main function:**

```
int main() {
    vector<B> vec;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vec.push_back(B(i)); <------------ Issue is here
    }

    cout << "adding complete" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "x = " << (vec[i].a)->x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong in this code?

**EDIT:** Error `double free or memory corruption`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Heed the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

Everyone else has already harped on this so I won't dive further.

To address the usage you are apparently trying to accomplish (and conform to the Rule of Three in the process of elimination), try the following. While everyone is absolutely correct about proper management of ownership of dynamic members, your specific sample can easily be made to avoid their use *entirely*.

**Class A**

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int x);
        int x;
};

A::A(int x) 
   : x(x)
{
}
```

**Class B**

```
class B {
    public:
        B(int x);
        A a;
};

B::B(int x) 
    : a(x) 
{
}
```

**Main Program**

```
int main() {
    vector<B> vec;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vec.push_back(B(i));
    }

    cout << "adding complete" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "x = " << vec[i].a.x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Bottom Line**
Don't use dynamic allocation unless you have a good reason to, **and** it is lifetime-guarded by contained variables such as smart pointers or classes that vigorously practice the Rule of Three.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to define a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, so your wrapped object is being `delete`d by some `B`.... then again when some copy of `B` goes out of scope.

In this case it's the `B(i)` temporary on the line you've identified, as well as an implementation-defined number of copies within the vector.

Abide by the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is due to the fact that "plain" C/C++ pointers have no concept of *ownership*. When a pointer gets copied, both copies<sup>*</sup> "think" that they own the data, leading to double-deletion.

In recognition of this fact, the designers of the C++ standard library introduced a `unique_ptr<T>` class that helps you address problems like that.

---

<sup>*</sup> One copy of the pointer is in the instance of `B` passed to `push_back`; the other copy of the pointer is in the instance entered into the `vector`.

Comment: In C++11, as well as fixing the class `B` using `unique_ptr`, you can write `vec.emplace_back(i)` instead of `vec.push_back(B(i))`. But that's an aside, even with that change you do still need to fix `B`, one way or another.